# com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: Error finding JNDI name (LMD)---- Error code:-2147467259

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have to generate pdf dynamically using crystal report but after setting parameters I am getting this error

```
18:29:45,385 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-6) com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: Error finding JNDI name (LMD)---- Error code:-2147467259 Error code name:failed

18:29:45,387 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-6)  at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.a(SourceFile:2284)

18:29:45,387 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-6)  at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.a(SourceFile:2304)

18:29:45,387 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-6)  at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.if(SourceFile:736)

18:29:45,387 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-6)  at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.a(SourceFile:166)

18:29:45,388 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-6)  at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.a(SourceFile:528)

18:29:45,388 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-6)  at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.call(SourceFile:526)

18:29:45,388 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-6)  at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ThreadGuard.syncExecute(SourceFile:102)

18:29:45,389 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-6)  at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.for(SourceFile:524)

18:29:45,389 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-6)  at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.int(SourceFile:423)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't find your data source, LMD. Check your JNDI url/connection string, or whatever db connection parameters you have set if some other function is generating the connection string for you.

Otherwise, there are all sorts of reasons for not being able to find a data source, and more detail would be needed to give you any help.